# MS Access, Conditional Formatting for Short Time Value highlight above 06:30

Tags: ms-access, time, conditional-formatting

I don't see any related questions to conditional formatting regarding a time value. I have a report that needs to highlight any times greater than 06:30. I had the field set to Medium Time (06:30 AM) but the AM/PM may be an issue so now I am trying simply short time.

I have tried every combination or Left, Right, Hour, Minute - the real issue is simply the 30 minutes between 06:00 and 06:30 that is the issue. I can do a simple "Expression is Left([Time],2)>5 to get anything above 06:00, but I don't want anything from 06:00 to 06:30 highlighted.

Is the solution to this converting the time to a number first, and then applying the conditional format?

Comment: Expression is: `TimeValue([YourTimeField])>TimeValue("06:30 AM")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use strings for handling date and time. No exceptions.

You have dedicated functions for this, like:

```
DateDiff("n", #06:30:00#, [TimeField]) > 0
```

or even:

```
DateDiff("n", TimeSerial(6, 30, 0), [TimeField]) > 0
```

If a date value is included, strip that with *TimeValue*:

```
DateDiff("n", #06:30:00#, TimeValue([TimeField])) > 0
```